# How to force ranger to edit html files?

Tags: debian, file-management, ranger

I am using [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/documentation.html) and every time I try to edit an HTML file ranger will open that file with the browser instead of editing it with Vim.

How can I force ranger to edit HTML instead of loading them in my browser?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39818761/1908115

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to edit the configuration for this. Just press <kbd>r</kbd> and then select your editor.

By default this will be `2 | ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"`, so you'd just press <kbd>2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (assuming that `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` are set to your preferred editor).

See Krv Perera's answer if you'd like to change the default ("`0`") program in `rifle.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you find yourself mostly editing HTML files and rarely running them from ranger, then you can put this line `ext x?html? = ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$1"` on top of all the other rules for websites in your `rifle.conf` file.

This way ranger will automatically open the file in your editor of choice and if you need to run it in browser you can press `r` and then select your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Press `r`

```
0 | firefox -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1 | chromium -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
2 | google-chrome -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
3 | w3m "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4 | ${VISUAL:-$EDITOR} -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
5 | "$PAGER" -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
6 | xdg-open -- "$@"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
8 | mkdir -p -- ${XDG_DATA_DIR:-$HOME/.ranger}/ranger-trash; mv -- "$@" ${XDG_DATA_DIR:-$HOME/.ranger}/ranger-trash
```

:open_with `vim`

Instead type a number I typed vim, and it's working.